# Lion + Xcode 4.1 deactivated iOS Simulator 3.x Testing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, osx-lion, ios-simulator

I searched for days, nothing found, no answer on apple dev forums, I want to be able to test my apps on older versions - on iOS Simulator!

I know - this is not the proper way of testing and not 100% reliable. But I can't afford getting another test-device with older iOS, aaand downgrading my existing devices seems to be a very tough task too - damn sure too tough for me...

Testing on iOS Simulator for 3.x versions will do enough good for those who didn't upgrade to 4.x yet and download my apps.

So please - anyone who was able to reactivate the older iOS Simulator SDKs on Lion / Xcode 4.1? - Don't tell me to set deployment target please :-)

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can install xcode 3.2.x in Lion, and it's will automatic installed in "developer-old" floder. Your xcode 4.1 is still available.
I also want to reactivate the older iOS Simulator SDKs on Lion / Xcode 4.1. ;)

NotMyName posted blow in devforums.apple.com

By reverting back to OS X 10.6.8, and Xcode 4.02, apparently.  :-(

Although it is worth noting that the Apple employees posting here have repeated a few times that this is an intended change, and one might guess that either the various simulator versions weren't particularly accurate on their API levels, or that it was just too much work to maintain.  I seem to remember there being some bugs in the block implementations at the various levels, for starters.

There's also the often reported mantra, "The simulator is NOT an accurate way of testing your app's behavior."

Answer (score 1):

You can't reactivate the iOS 3.x Simulator, you will need to install an older version of Xcode (one with the iOS 3.x SDK) along side Xcode 4.x (with the iOS 4.x SDK).

Comment: And you can't install an older version on Lion…

Comment: it was possible on older Xcode versions, but not with lion. however i was able to complete the installation process on a different directory. when I started Xcode 4.1 I still had no 3.x simulator. i checked up on the subdirectories - found under /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs that there is only the 4.3 available. I simply copied from the older xcode the 3.x SDK directories and restarted Xcode - et voila - iPhone Simulator 3.x showing up. Frustration returned because Xcode crashed everytime i tried to build & run on 3.x :-( ... so I guess gcamp is right in the end.