# How to use previous (3.x and 4.x) simulators within XCode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Does anyone know how to configure XCode so that the Destination drop down under Manage Schemes
encapsulats all previous simulators iOS 3.x and iOS 4.x? Currently the Destination drop down only
lists iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.0 devices. The only way, I am able to currently access previous simulators is by running
previous versions of XCode. I would like to run all simulators from XCode 4.2 without the need to revert.
I've already tried to change the deployment target. This does not work.

Thanks so much

Comment: This [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7521375) sounds good but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 4.3 set iOS Deployment Target to 4.3 (or earlier). Get the simulator from Xcode, Preferences, Downloads, Components.

According to @rckoenes: You can't reactivate the iOS 3.x Simulator, you will need to install an older version of Xcode (one with the iOS 3.x SDK) along side Xcode 4.x (with the iOS 4.x SDK), [see answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7271794/451475).